# SharePoint 2010: Problem trying to install web part using power shell

Tags: deployment, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I'm trying to deploy my first web part on 2010. I developed a web part using VS2008 and tested it on SP2007.

I copied the CAB to the 2010 server and tried to use the power shell to install it:

```
PS C:\Users\sa_portalt> Install-SPWebPartPack -LiteralPath "c:\transfer\webparts\redirectwebpart.cab" -Name "RedirectWebPart"
Install-SPWebPartPack : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:22
+ Install-SPWebPartPack <<<<  -LiteralPath "c:\transfer\webparts\redirectwebpart.cab" -Name "RedirectWebPart"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Install-SPWebPartPack], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletInstallWebPartPack
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this the right way to install web parts?

Answer (score 2):

If you can, I recommend you upgrade to Visual Studio 2010 which has built-in support for SharePoint 2010.  When you build a project built from the SharePoint template it will create the wsp for you.  You can also immediately deploy to the local server from VS2010 so you never need to get into PowerShell on your local development machine.

When you need to deploy to a different server, you can then run

`Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\webparts\MyWebPart.wsp` to add the solution to Central Administation
and then

`Install-SPSolution -Identify MyWebPart.wsp -WebApplication http://mySharePointserver` to deploy the solution to the specified web application

Comment: at the moment we are focussing still on SP2007. I am making the initial tests with SP2010 and just want to investigate the migration of our web parts. We don't yet have VS2010.

Answer (score 1):

This was the first article I found that provided the actual answer, however, in the Install-SPSolution, there is a typeo, the -Indentify parameter should be -Identity

Also, in most cases (if adding to the GAC) need to add the -GACDeployment to the Install-SPSolution.

So the line should look like:
Install-SPSolution -Identity BasicWebPart.wsp -WebApplication http://vsp -GACDeployment